# Adding a git submodule from a remote repository with gitpython

Tags: python, git, gitpython

For automating some of our workflows I am implementing some Python scripts which create project templates. The content of a project template is located in a folder which also is a local git repository. So the project in the end will be linked and pushed to a remote repository on our company server. Each project additionally uses some of our own created libraries which are added as a git submodule into the project folder and is part of the project git repository.

So my script should now first create the local project git repository which I do by using Gitpython with the following code:
`Repo.init(os.path.join(sRepoPath, '.git'), bare=True)`

After the repository is created, I want to add one or more remote repositories as a submodule and then clone them into the project folder. But I can't find out how to do it from the Gitpython documentation. It does not cover such a case with remotes as a submodule.

I've already tried several code combinations from the Gitpython documentation. Something like (of course not working):

```
mainRepo = Repo(sDestinationRepoPath)
test_remote = mainRepo.create_remote('submodule', "ssh://git@bb.mycompany.corp:1234/fwlib/system_lib.git")
mainRepo.create_submodule(test_remote)
```

But I can't sort it out how it should be done. Can anyone tell me how to do it?